# docker login does not work as part of ci cd but works locally

Tags: azure, powershell, docker

Docker login command in my powershell script to authenticate to Azure Container Registry gives authentication required error while running as part of my CI/CD setup in Azure DevOps, while the exact same code authenticates perfectly from my local powershell session. To make sure the values are the same, I have hardcoded the values in the script for all variables: $registeryLoginServer, $SP_APP_ID, $SP_PASSWD. Checked docker versions on both local powershell and during build, the same version. How can the same code with the same arguments can result in a successful authentication locally and not during build?

```
"$SP_PASSWD" | docker login $registeryLoginServer -u "$SP_APP_ID" --password-stdin
```

Following authentication with service principle as described [in this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal).

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo "$SP_PASSWD" | docker login $registeryLoginServer -u "$SP_APP_ID" --password-stdin`

Just specifying "$SP_PASSWD" won't pipe the value of variable to stdin.

If you are on windows, you might need to disable the newline added by echo command using set /p

`echo | set /p="your_password" | docker login --username your_username --password-stdin`

Comment: Trying now. Although, then my question is how come the same line does login succesfully on my local powershell session?

Comment: Unfortunately the same error: [error]docker : Error response from daemon: Get https://....azurecr.io/v2/: unauthorized: authentication 
required

Comment: [error]docker : Error response from daemon: Get https://xxx.azurecr.io/v2/: unauthorized: authentication 
required
At ....ps1:25 
char:25
+ ... P_PASSWD" | docker login $registeryLoginServer -u "$SP_APP_ID" --pass ...

+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error response ...cation required:String) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: I'm not sure of your error but why don't you use --password option of docker login instead of using -password-stdin and piping the password?

Comment: When I use --password then it fails with the error (not a warning but an error) that --password is not secure and I must use --password-stdin. What I cannot figure out is that the exact same variables with same hardcoded values and the same docker login line logs in succesfully on local and then fails during build.

Comment: What is your local OS where it works and what is the OS on which the CI/CD pipeline is running? Can you try the following if your CI/CD pipeline is running on Windows  system

`echo | set /p="your_password" | docker login --username your_username --password-stdin`

Comment: My local OS is windows 10. Build server is also configured to use a windows as in azure-pipelines.yml: "pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'"

Comment: Trying your suggestion now

Comment: @tubakaya Did you fix this? I have the same issue against the Azure container registry currently and the other solutions don't seem to work

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper No, I couldn't fix it after all. I moved to docker hub. That worked easily. Not sure why it was so impossible to login to Azure Container Registry. I couldn't find out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @tubakaya Thanks for the update. I actually got the login working in Azure DevOps build pipelines by using the Docker Command task which had a "login" option where I could select my linked ACR. Seemed to work OK, but can't pull images without a permission error. Part the way there at least.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper You might want to check the roles assigned to the service principle you are using. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles In my case the ACR was also acquired by infra as code, therefore using a specific ACR via the docker command task was not an option.